# How to Print Socket.io Data through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, socket.io

I have an object that i want to have displayed real time in html. I'm using *socket.io, express* and handlebars template engine.

Here is my `routes/index.js`:

```
/* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        Item.find({}, {'item_name':1, 'stock':1}, function(err, docs) {
            res.render('index', { title: 'Express'});
            io.on('connection', function (socket) {
                socket.emit('items', { item: docs });
            });
        });
    });
```

If i code `res.render('index', { title: 'Express', item: docs});` and print the data on html like:

```
<div class="list-group list-item-status" id="listItem">
     {{#each items }}
         <li class="list-group-item" id="listGroup">
         {{#each this }}
               {{ this.item_name }}
                <span class="badge">{{ this.stock }}</span>
         {{/each}}
         </li>
     {{/each}}
</div>
```

I can display all data that i want. But how do i manipulate the DOM to display the data (to replace above code) by using jQuery on client-side with socket.io ?
I put this script in `views/index.hbs`:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
        socket.on('items', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });    
</script>
```

In the console, i can see the data object.
[image]

Any help would be appreaciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you expecting `{{#each items }}` to execute on the data sent from socket.io? At the moment you're receiving data from socket.io and console logging it, nothing else.

Comment: I just want to list all the data by using jquery (to replace the general handlebars code), i've tried to create this code http://pastebin.com/Wv81PDx7 but i got `[object Object]` printed 12x (12x object length)

Comment: do you want to iterate over `docs`, in `{ item: docs }` which I am assuming is an array?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that you need to do something with the data once you receive it.

```
<script>
    var socket = io();
        socket.on('items', function (data) {
            $('#listItem').text(data[0].item_name);
        });    
</script>
```

This is going to just stick the `item_name` from the first element in the array into some DOM element. Pretty straight forward, and pretty clearly not what you want.

I'm going to assume that you want to use Handlebars to render a pretty list, since that's what you show in your question. So, building off of the template you've given above:

```
<script>

    const templateString = `
    {{#each items }}
        <li class="list-group-item" id="listGroup">
            {{#each this }}
                {{ this.item_name }}
                <span class="badge">{{ this.stock }}</span>
            {{/each}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    `;

    const template = Handlebars.compile(templateString);

    var socket = io();
        socket.on('items', function (data) {
            $('#listItem').html(template({ items: data });
        });    

</script>
```

In short, I'm creating a Handlebars template function from the template that you showed in your question, then rendering an HTML fragment and inserting it into the DOM every time new data is received from the server.

Comment: thanks for your response. I've solved my problem with this code: http://pastebin.com/gs3Wkpdx